# Задачи на циклы

Tags: циклы, java

Хочу попрактиковаться с циклами в java. Подкиньте, пожалуйста, задачек.

Answer (score 2):

1. Наиболее оптимальный по скорости
       работы вариант цикла for
2. Создайте массив целых чисел,
       заполните его только четными
       числами, а затем каждый второй
       элемент умножьте на предидущий.
       Используйте все варианты циклов.
3. Каким видами цикла for можно обойти
       список или массив(а вообще объект
       реализующий интерфейс итератора) в
       java?
4. Выбирете из массива каждый третий элемент(без if и break)

Все из головы взял, так что если что могут быть неточности. Пробуйте и ставьте себе задачи сами, особенно если пишите проект для себя, то это просто будет.

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут - [CodingBat](http://codingbat.com/) - вроде есть такие.

Answer (score 1):

1. Дан массив NxN необходимо его заполнить по спирали

   Входные данные
   4

   Выходные данные
   1 2 3 4
   12 13 14 5  
   11 16 15 6 
   10 9 8 7
2. Дан массив NxN необходимо его заполнить его змейкой

   Входные данные
   4
   Выходные данные
   1 2 6 7
   3 5 8 13
   4 9 12 14
   10 11 15 16

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - обработка массива цифр (заодно и массивы потренируете): сортировки (по возрастанию, убыванию), выборка кратных чисел, наибольшее/наименьшее значение.
С двумерными массивами - сложение/умножение/транспонирование матриц.